# Jinja2 slower than Django?

Tags: django, jinja2

I have just switched to Jinja2 from the Django template engine and it's 50% slower sometimes but not on average. How can this be? It there something I have missed?

P.S. Found out in the meantime that it's lots of times faster in rendering a 'small' page:

```
Django: rendered 0:00:00.003929
Jinja2: rendered 0:00:00.000959
Django: rendered 0:00:00.325080
Jinja2: rendered 0:00:00.351776
```

So where it matters it's slower, where it doesn't it's faster :|

Comment: What are you asking exactly?

Comment: How can this be? It there something I have missed?

Comment: Could you post an example of a slow template and a fast template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Jinja2 can be slower only if you access object properties that do queries to the db.
If you make sure the queries get done before the template by providing the template only with strings, it's orders of magnitude faster than Django.